# How to branch a SAX parser depending on the first known tag?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm having a hard time parsing multiple different XML files on Android using the built-in SAX parser.

Nate and Aron Saunders have helped me with the right approach to this problem but I struggle with implementing it. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583876/how-to-parse-different-xml-files-using-sax-on-android).

I have ten different XML files.

Example `ResponseOne`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseOne>
  <InnerTag Id="1">
  </InnerTag>
</ResponseOne>
```

Example `ResponseTwo`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseTwo>
  <AnotherInnerTag State="2">
  </AnotherInnerTag>
</ResponseTwo>
```

And so on. Every root tag is different. Now I know that I could branch the parser to trigger a different event on every root tag but I'm not quite sure I know how exactly do achieve this.

How would I tell my SAX handler that he should parse for `AnotherInnerTag` with its attributes based on the root tag?

Comment: You use lots of flags and condition checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Android SAX parser is similar to the Java SE SAX parser the following strategy could be used:

- [Using SAX to parse common XML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405702/using-sax-to-parse-common-xml-elements/3409270#3409270)

Comment: Thanks. I'm always amused by the fact that all those answers were on StackOverflow and I couldn't find them even after hours of search.